# Java EE, JBoss: @Asynchronous does not allow method overloading

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, overloading, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

Does anybody has an idea why method overloading in combination with the `@Asynchronous` annotation does not work (I tested only on JBoss 6.0).

Example:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public interface AsyncBean {

    @Asynchronous
    public void test(int a){
        // a lot of time-consuming calculations with a
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void test(int a, int b) {
        // a lot of time-consuming calculations with a and b
    }
}
```

Calls to any of the overloaded `test()` methods of the `AsyncBean` are **not** asynchronous. Howewer, giving up overloading (renaming one of the methods) results in asynchronous processing of the method calls.

Is there a reason why this does not work?

Comment: It should work.  It looks like a JBoss bug to me.